# How can I break a navbar into two rows with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm having trouble trying to break the navbar to have `navbar-brand` in one row, and the collapse menu in another

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 float-end">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no more `-xs-` that is the default breakpoint so the proper classes would be `col-12 col-md-6`; however this is still not enough while inside the `.navbar`.
In such cases you can insert a manual break with:

```html
<div class="w-100 d-md-none"></div>
```

That will take the entire width forcing the elements to wrap only below the `md` breakpoint.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container text-center text-md-start">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <a class="navbar-brand m-0" href="#">Navbar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 d-md-none"></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```